# Building rosconsole_bridge on OSX fails

Tags: ros-groovy, osx

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello,

when trying to build rosconsole_bridge on OSX it fails with this error:

```
100%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/rosconsole_bridge.dir/src/bridge.cpp.o
/Users/tatsch/ros_catkin_ws/src/rosconsole_bridge/src/bridge.cpp:52:24: error: 
      no member named 'LOG_INFO' in namespace 'console_bridge'
  case console_bridge::LOG_INFO: 
       ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^
/Users/tatsch/ros_catkin_ws/src/rosconsole_bridge/src/bridge.cpp:61:24: error: 
      no member named 'LOG_WARN' in namespace 'console_bridge'
  case console_bridge::LOG_WARN:
       ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^
/Users/tatsch/ros_catkin_ws/src/rosconsole_bridge/src/bridge.cpp:70:24: error: 
      no member named 'LOG_ERROR' in namespace 'console_bridge'
  case console_bridge::LOG_ERROR:
       ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^
/Users/tatsch/ros_catkin_ws/src/rosconsole_bridge/src/bridge.cpp:98:47: error: 
      no member named 'LOG_DEBUG' in namespace 'console_bridge'
  console_bridge::setLogLevel(console_bridge::LOG_DEBUG);
                              ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^
4 errors generated.
```

Does anyone already have a solution or a suggestion how to solve this?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/64872/building-rosconsole_bridge-on-osx-fails/) by [J.M.T.](https://answers.ros.org/users/3816/j.m.t./) on ROS Answers with karma: 266 on 2013-06-11

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) on 2013-06-11**:
@Dirk Thomas is this related to the backport to groovy?

**Comment by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) on 2013-06-12**:
This appears to be an issue on all platforms: http://jenkins.willowgarage.com:8080/view/GbinP32/job/ros-groovy-rosconsole-bridge_binarydeb_precise_i386/64/console

**Comment by [William](https://answers.ros.org/users/10/william/) on 2013-06-12**:
@J.M.T. we are working on fixing the issue, if you want to work around it you can use an older version of `console_bridge`, but it is probably best to just wait for us to release `rosconsolse_bridge` (it will happen shortly) and then update your version or `rosconsolse_bridge` when we do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I just released rosconsole_bridge 0.2.7 into Groovy. That will fix the build issue. Sorry for the inconvenience.

---

Originally posted by [Dirk Thomas](https://answers.ros.org/users/2575/dirk-thomas/) with karma: 16276 on 2013-06-12

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0